# How to get full sentence using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

As of now, I'm parsing PDF using [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) later I will be parsing other documents (.docx/.doc). Using PDFBox, I'm getting all file content into one string. Now, I wanted to get complete sentence wherever a user define words matches.

For example:

```
... some text here..
Raman took more than 12 year to complete his schooling and now he
is pursuing higher study.
Relational Database. 
... some text here ..
```

If user gives the input `year`, then it should return whole sentence.

**Expected Output:**

```
Raman took more than 12 year to complete his schooling and now he
    is pursuing higher study.
```

I'm trying below code, but it showing nothing. Can anyone correct this

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\w|\\W]*+[YEAR]+[\\w]*+.");
```

Also, If I have to include multiple words to match as `OR` condition, then what should I make change in my regex ?

**Please note all words are in uppercase.**

Comment: What are the rules to constitute a sentence?

Comment: Note that "." has a special meaning in regex

Comment: @anubhava wherever specific words matches which will be provided at runtime by user. In above case, it is `YEAR`, which I have mentioned. So, it should return whole sentence where it find `YEAR` word.

Comment: **So, it should return whole sentence where it find `YEAR` word** What are rules to define a **whole sentence**. Text ending with DOT cannot be a sentence since a sentence can have `Mr.` or `Sr.` or `Jr.` etc as well.

Comment: Ok, then suggest me, what should I use ?  Can we check later once we have that word ? I mean the length of string/line is more than 5 or more ?

Comment: I have answered many regex questions and have read so many articles on regex problems but haven't come across any regex solution that can reliably define a sentence. Loose definitions can be starting with a capital letter that comes after DOT or `?` and ends with `DOT` or `?` but bear in mind that will also break down for many cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not try to put everything into the single regexp. There's a standard Java class [`java.text.BreakIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html) which can be used to find the sentence boundaries.

```
public static String getSentence(String input, String word) {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(word, Pattern.LITERAL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
                             .matcher(input);
    if(matcher.find()) {
        BreakIterator br = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
        br.setText(input);
        int start = br.preceding(matcher.start());
        int end = br.following(matcher.end());
        return input.substring(start, end);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "... some text...\n Raman took more than 12 year to complete his schooling and now he\nis pursuing higher study. Relational Database. \n... some text...";
    System.out.println(getSentence(input, "YEAR"));
}
```

Comment: I have  a question, will it still work if immediate sentence matches criteria ? I tried, but didn't worked.

Comment: Ok. got it. you have return statement. Let me check myself, I will update you for the same.

Comment: One question, how to pass multiple words to match ? Is it fine `YEAR|%`. If I'm looking for sentence where `%` or `YEAR` found ?

Comment: @jWeaver, if you want either of these words, you may just call `getSentence(input, "YEAR")`, then `getSentence(input, "%")`.

Comment: Correct. But, I was confirming if we would alternative. Thanks.

Comment: Test this with `String input = "... some text...\n Raman took more than 12 year to complete his schooling with Mr. Bean and now he\nis pursuing higher study. Relational Database. \n... some text...";`

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern re = Pattern.compile("[^.!?\\s][^.!?]*(?:[.!?](?!['\"]?\\s|$)      [^.!?]*)*[.!?]?['\"]?(?=\\s|$)", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.COMMENTS);
 Matcher reMatcher = re.matcher(result);

 while (reMatcher.find()) {

 System.out.println(reMatcher.group());
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A small fix to @Tagir Valeev answer to prevent index out of bounds exceptions.

```
 private String getSentence(String input, String word) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(word , Pattern.LITERAL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
                .matcher(input);
        if(matcher.find()) {
            BreakIterator br = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
            br.setText(input);
            int start = br.preceding(matcher.start());
            int end = br.following(matcher.end());

            if(start == BreakIterator.DONE) {
                start = 0;
            }

            if(end == BreakIterator.DONE) {
                end = input.length();
            }

            return input.substring(start, end);
        }

        return null;
    }
```